# Can't assign value to integer signal in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am using a programmable-logic to decode a sequence of long or short impulses into latin letters according to morse code. I am using VHDL to describe our design, to be precise I'm using Quartus Prime for the design and ModelSim for the simulations. My CPLD is an **ALTERA MAX-V 5M160ZE64C5**.

Here is my code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all ;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity SauvezLesMorses is
    port
    (
        -- Input ports
        clk : in std_logic;
        message : in std_logic;
        display : in std_logic;
        start : in std_logic;

        -- Output ports
        seg14 : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
        lengthLED : out std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity SauvezLesMorses;

architecture SauvezLesMorses_arch of SauvezLesMorses is
type state_t is (A, B, C);
signal state : state_t;
signal count : integer range 0 to 4 := 0;   
signal clk_cnt : integer range 0 to 21 := 0;
signal morse : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin


process (clk, start)
variable vectorDummy : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin
    if (start = '1') then
        state <= A;
        count <= 0;
        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
        morse <= "0000";
        lengthLED <= '0';

    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        case state is


            -- Idle, listening
            when A =>
                if  (display = '0') then
                    if (message = '1' and count < 4) then
                        state <= B;
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                        count <= count;
                        morse <= morse;
                        lengthLED <= '0';
                        clk_cnt <= 0;
                    else
                        state <= A;
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                        count <= count;
                        morse <= morse;
                        lengthLED <= '0';
                    end if;
                else
                    state <= C;
                    count <= count;
                    morse <= morse;
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                end if;


            -- Measuring impulse length 
            when B =>
                if (display = '0') then
                    if (message = '1') then
                        state <= B;
                        count <= count;
                        morse <= morse;
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                        if (clk_cnt < 20) then
                            clk_cnt <= (1 + clk_cnt);
                            lengthLED <= '0';
                        else
                            clk_cnt <= 21;
                            lengthLED <= '1';
                        end if;
                    else
                        state <= A;
                        if (clk_cnt < 21) then
                            morse <= morse;
                        else
                            case count is
                                when 0 => vectorDummy := "1000";
                                when 1 => vectorDummy := "0100";
                                when 2 => vectorDummy := "0010";
                                when 3 => vectorDummy := "0001";
                                when others => vectorDummy := "0000";
                            end case;
                            morse <= morse or vectorDummy;
                        end if;
                        count <= count + 1;
                        lengthLED <= '0';
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                    end if;
                else
                    state <= C;
                    count <= count;
                    morse <= morse;
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                end if;


            -- Displaying converted character to user
            when C =>
                if (display = '0') then
                    state <= A;
                    count <= 0;
                    seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    morse <= "0000";
                else
                    state <= C;
                    count <= count;
                    morse <= morse;
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    if(count = 1) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "10011110001000"; --E
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "10000000100010"; --T
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    elsif(count = 2) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0100" => seg14 <= "11101110001000"; --A
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "01101101000100"; --N
                            when "1100" => seg14 <= "01101101010000"; --M
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "00000000100010"; --I
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    elsif(count = 3) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "10110110001000"; --S
                            when "0010" => seg14 <= "01111100000000"; --U
                            when "0100" => seg14 <= "11001110001100"; --R
                            when "0110" => seg14 <= "01101100000101"; --W
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "11110000100010"; --D
                            when "1010" => seg14 <= "00001110010100"; --K
                            when "1100" => seg14 <= "10111100001000"; --G
                            when "1110" => seg14 <= "11111100000000"; --O
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    elsif(count = 4) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "01101110001000"; --H
                            when "0001" => seg14 <= "00001100010001"; --V
                            when "0010" => seg14 <= "10001110001000"; --F
                            when "0100" => seg14 <= "00011100000000"; --L
                            when "0110" => seg14 <= "11001110001000"; --P
                            when "0111" => seg14 <= "01111000000000"; --J
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "11110000101010"; --B
                            when "1001" => seg14 <= "00000001010101"; --X
                            when "1010" => seg14 <= "10011100000000"; --C
                            when "1011" => seg14 <= "00000001010010"; --Y
                            when "1100" => seg14 <= "10010000010001"; --Z
                            when "1101" => seg14 <= "11111100000100"; --Q
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    else
                        seg14 <= "11111111111111";
                    end if ;
                end if;


        end case;
    end if;
end process;


end architecture SauvezLesMorses_arch ;
```

A modelsim simulation with parameters

```
force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/clk 1 0, 0 {25000000000 ps} -r {50 ms}
force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/display 0 0, 1 {9000000000000 ps} -r {18 sec}
force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/message 0 0, 1 {3200000000000 ps} -r {6.4 sec}
force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/start 1 0 -cancel {0.5 sec}
run 40 sec
```

which yields :

[Modelsim Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHpc6.png)

clearly shows that :

- `clk_cnt` never increases but rather remains zero for 40 seconds
- `count` is neither set to 0 by the activation of `start` nor from the desactivation of display (i.e. the transition of `state` from `C` to `A`).

Would you have any idea why?

---

*P.S. I know that I am positively not running a proper testbench. So even if I should, please do not remind it to me unless you know it is part of the answer to my question.*

Comment: And yet were you to use a [testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqRxv.png) both clk_cnt and count exhibit seemingly proper behavior.

Comment: Really? Allright then damn me and my corner-cutting compulsions, let's do a testbench. Thank you!

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update, para 3 *...If updating a signal causes the current value of that signal to change, then an event is said to have occurred on the signal, unless the update occurs by application of the `vhpi_put_value` function with an update mode of `vhpiDeposit` or `vhpiForce` to an object that represents the signal. ...* Likely the same mechanism used by Modelsim's force or FLI. You don't get events for a force update.

Comment: Interesting. Then let this question be the enduring remainder that simulating without testbench is thick. As am I. 

Thank you once again.

Comment: Not thick. Try finding an answer looking through the force SE command or other Modelsim documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A force updating a signal value doesn't generate an event.

See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update, para 3

> ... If updating a signal causes the current value of that signal to change, then an *event* is said to have occurred on the signal, unless the update occurs by application of the `vhpi_put_value` function with an update mode of `vhpiDeposit` or `vhpiForce` to an object that represents the signal. ...

Likely the same mechanism used by Modelsim's force or FLI.

With a testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity slm_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of slm_tb is
    -- Input ports
    signal clk:         std_logic := '1';
    signal message:     std_logic := '0';
    signal display:     std_logic := '0';
    signal start:       std_logic := '1';
    -- Output ports
    signal seg14:       std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
    signal lengthLED:   std_logic;
begin

DUT:
    entity work.sauvezlesmorses
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            message => message,
            display => display,
            start   => start,
            seg14   => seg14,
            lengthLED => lengthLED
        );

-- force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/clk 1 0, 0 {25000000000 ps} -r {50 ms}
-- force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/display 0 0, 1 {9000000000000 ps} -r {18 sec}
-- force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/message 0 0, 1 {3200000000000 ps} -r {6.4 sec}
-- force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/start 1 0 -cancel {0.5 sec}
-- run 40 sec

-- stimulus generators:
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 25 ms;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 40 sec then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
DISP:
    process
    begin
        wait for 9 sec;
        display <= not display;
        if now > 35 sec then  -- stop simulation at 40 sec
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
MSG:
    process
    begin
        wait for 3.2 sec;
        message <= not message;
        if now > 35 sec then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
ST:
    process
    begin
        wait for 0.5 sec;
        start <= 'U';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

You do get events:

[image: slm_tb.png]